# How to Display data from Database in JDBC -Java

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to search book by ISBN no.I have below tables in Oracle SQL Developer. SQL query to search book by ISBN runs good in SQL Developer but when I am trying to run in JDBC this one goes into 
 **else part** and prints **"No records found"** although the ISBN no is already there in the Book table.

When I run function on another PC this one runs but got stuck in my laptop. This one is very weird error.**
I am able to run insert function in same table but not able to run search function.

This one is working in one pc and not working in another PC. What could be the reason?
Any help i most welcomed. Thank you.

I have 3 tables mentioned below. I have past the my code below with SearchISBN functionaliy

```
CREATE TABLE Book(
ISBN INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Title VARCHAR2(50),
PublisherID INT,
AuthorID INT,
PublishDate DATE,
AvailableCopies INT);

CREATE TABLE Author(
AuthorID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
AuthorName VARCHAR2(50),
Email VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Publisher(
PublisherID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
PublisherName VARCHAR2(50),
Address VARCHAR2(50),
Phone INT
);
```

---

```
public static void FindByISBN(String[] args) throws SQLException
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int isbn, cnt=0;
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try
        {   
            System.out.println("Enter ISBN Number:");
            isbn = in.nextInt();

            System.out.println("\n\tBook Search by ISBN\n");
            conn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////   Query for Find Book

            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT b.isbn as isbn, b.title as title, a.name as aname, p.name as pname FROM book b, publisher p, author a where b.publisherid=p.publisherid "
                 + " AND b.authorid=a.authorid AND b.isbn LIKE '%" + isbn + "%'");


            /////////////////////////////////////////// Display Results

            while(rs.next())
            {
                    cnt+=1;

                System.out.println(""+ rs.getInt("isbn") + "\t||\t" + rs.getString("title")+ "\t||\t"+ rs.getString("aname") + "\t||\t" +rs.getString("pname")+ "");
            }

            ///////////////////////////////////////// If Output not found
            if(cnt==0)
            {
                System.err.println("No Search Found !! \n");
            }         
          } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error Message: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.err.println("Error Code: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            System.err.println("SQL State: " + ex.getSQLState());
        }
        finally{
             if(rs != null){
                rs.close();
            }
              if(stmt != null){
                stmt.close();
            }
            if(conn != null){
                conn.close();
            }
        }        
    }
```

Comment: did you try your sql query in some interactive sql client? does it work as expected there?

Comment: Yes..I did,,It is working good in sql client but when I try using JDBC it always display "No search found !!"

Comment: It just tyr not sure about this but use `prepareStatement` instead of using `createStatement`.

Comment: Since when is ISBN an INT? An ISBN looks like `978-0-300-14424-6`. That's a varchar, not an int.